Running Full Stack Postgres App in Docker but not saving to DB
I have containerised a full stack API app which is a simple contact form and thankyou page that is using react-hook-form, axios and an ORM with Sequelize and its Contact.create() method.
When the data is submitted I get to the Thankyou page but i do not see it being saved in the psql db and see no new records. However the data is saved successfully when running without Docker.
I dont see any issues in the Docker Logs and the form submits successfully in console. I have checked the db connections.
Here is my query and onsubmit function. I see the object being returned in the console both locally and in Docker but in Docker i do not get the 'submitted' console.log. Im expecting to see the new record in psql and 'submitted' while running in Docker.
  async (req, res) => {

    const errors = validationResult(req)

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }

    const { first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, message } = req.body;


    try {
      await Contact.create({ first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, message })
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'form submitted' })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error saving data:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'an error occurred' })
    }
  })

 const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log('Form Data:', data);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(apiSubmit, data)

      if (response.status === 200) {
        navigate('/Thankyou')
        console.log('submitted');

      }
    } catch (error) {
    }
  };

Here is my Docker-compose.
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - server
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_URL=${REACT_APP_API_URL}

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:


DB connections
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: false,
});

export default sequelize;

import sequelize from '../sequelize.js';

const syncDatabase = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync();
  } catch (error) {
  }
};

syncDatabase();

export default syncDatabase;



What have you set DATABASE_URL to?

DATABASE_URL=postgresql://username:password@db:5432/contact_form
